# ArrayList Get - error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I'm new to both enums and ArrayLists, I was assigned to make a program to grade 15 answers in a True or False quiz. My program works fine up until the .get function where it puts the cannot find the symbol error. I'm  not sure why at all. Is it something to do with using a string and my enum type together?

```
public enum acceptedAnswer {T, F}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
  String answerKey = "TTTFFTFFFTFFTTF";
  String temp = "";
  String userChoice;
  int numOfStudents = 0;


  int maxScore = 0;
    int maxId = 0;
    int minScore = 15;
    int minId = 0;
    int sumOfScores = 0;
  double average = 0.0;

  System.out.print("Enter the amount of students tests to be graded: ");
   numOfStudents = scan.nextInt();
  scan.nextLine();

  int[] score = new int[numOfStudents];
  acceptedAnswer[] answers = new acceptedAnswer[15];
  List student = new ArrayList();

        for (int j = 0; j < numOfStudents; j++)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
       {
           System.out.print("Enter the answer to question " + (i+1) + " for student " + (j+1) + ": ");
           userChoice = scan.nextLine();
        answers[i] = acceptedAnswer.valueOf(userChoice);
        temp += answers[i];
     }
      System.out.println();
     student.add(temp); 
     temp = "";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
        temp = answers.get(i);
            if (temp.charAt(j) == answerKey.charAt(j))
                score[i] ++;
        }
          sumOfScores += score[i];
        }
```

Comment: `answers` is an array, not an `ArrayList`.  Use `answers[i]`.

Comment: When did SO become a tutoring site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
temp = answers.get(i);
```

with

```
temp = answers[i];
```

because answers is an array.

Comment: Great .. if that did the trick then click the Accepted Answer :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer : An array is not an ArrayList. Declare it as an ArrayList or access the values by direct index like

```
temp = answers[i]
```